# Web part not available to add in the Workbench which is hosted on SharePoint Library

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am building my first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1). Everything works perfect no issues with the following.

1. Successfully set up Machine with NodeJs, Gulp, Yeoman etc
2. Got the Dev Tenant and other setup on it
3. Got all the scaffolding for first web part using yo command
4. Ran `Gulp Serve` command, I can see, add, and play with the helloworld web part on the `local:4321` workbench

**Now**(*problem starts here*) as per the instructions I open the Workbench page which is hosted on the SharePoint. After accepting the load unsafe script the page opens up. But when I click on that `Plus` sign there is no hello world web part in the list to add.

Am I missing any step? Video and instruction which I followed does nothing special to get this web part in the list.

[image]

Comment: I tried but the issue not resolved for me. can you explain in detail..?

Answer (score 3):

After scratching my head for some time, I realized that the Gulp task was cancelled. So I did the following

1. Re ran the `Gulp serve` command. Which opened the browser with `local:4321` workbench.
2. Without cancelling the Gulp Task, I re open the SharePoint hosted workbench.

Eureka!!!

The problem got solved, and I was able to see the hello world web part in the list.

[image]